# How to make resttemplate return only classes with relationship to the sent id

Tags: java, spring, one-to-many, resttemplate

I want to send a request which returns only the classes with a relationship to a sent class or id(if id -> find the class with that id in database) and then returns those classes.

Say I have the following relationships in my db:

```
Foo1 -- Bar1    
     |__Bar2

Foo2 -- Bar3
```

My goal is so send a request which returns a List who has a relationship to Foo1.

```
class Foo{
private id;
@OneToMany
private List<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar {
private id;
@ManyToOne
private Foo foo;
}
```

So I thought the following was the correct solution: 
Client side:

```
public List<Bar> getBarsInFoo(String fooId)
        {
                return Arrays.stream(restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL + "/" + fooId, Bar[].class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

Server side:

```
GetMapping("/foo/{id}")
    public List<Bar> getBarsInFoo(@PathVariable long id){
        return fooService.getFooById(id).getBars();
    }
```

I expect to be returned a List but i am currently getting a 'springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null' error. Im sure my restcall is wrong, how can I ask for a list and send an id to sort out the correct data on the server side?

Comment: first point check your url and use `getForEntity` or `exchange` method instead of `getForObject`

Comment: url is correct. Checking ur suggestions now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At your client side try for the below code:

```
 return restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URL + "/" + fooId, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Bar>>() {
                }).getBody();
```